# How to Receive URL-Encoded Form Data in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I'm currently learning Next.js 13, and I've created a form in my application to submit a username and password to the server. The form action path is set to /submit, and the request method is POST. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to receive and process the URL-encoded form data on the server-side.

Here's a simplified version of my form:

```
<form action="/submit" method="post">
  <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

  <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my Next.js application, how can I access and process the data submitted via this form? Specifically, I want to retrieve the username and password fields.

I've looked into using req.body in my Middleware function importing NextRequest, but it seems that it's not populated with the form data by default. Do I need to configure something special to handle URL-encoded form data in Next.js 13?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable

Comment: Use `await req.formData()` in your middleware, and see whether thats populated.

Comment: @RobinThomas Thank you. 
now my code is 
```
let data = await req.formData()
let username = data.get('username')
let password = data.get('password')
```
now its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive FormData in your Next.js middleware, you need to use:

```
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  const data = await req.formData()
  const username = data.get('username')
  const password = data.get('password')

  ...
}
```

Its not available in `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

As a different approach, instead of using a [route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers): You can use [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations). When invoked in a form, the action automatically receives the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object. You don't need to use `React.useState` to manage fields, instead, you can extract the data using the native [FormData methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#instance_methods).

```
export default async function MyPage() {
  const login = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";
    const username = formData.get('username');
    const password = formData.get('password');
  };

  return (
    <form action={login}>}>
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

When working with forms that have many fields, you may want to consider using the [entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) method with JavaScript's [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). For example:

```js
const rawFormData = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
```

Of course you will want to have an error and loading state for your form when managing it this way, check out [this example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/next-forms) to get you started!